# How can I submit form data to other website in Angular4?

Tags: angular

I have a form on my Angular component. What I need to do is post form data to another site and open the page in new window.

Basically, I want it to be like

```
<form action="http://othersite.com/otherpage" target="_blank" method="POST">
   <input name="test">
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

For some reason Angular blocks the form processing. Is there any way to send form data to the page on another website?

Comment: Have you tried `<form ngNoForm ...>`? https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm

Comment: @JBNizet thanks, that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NgForm directive is applied to form elements, but [its selector](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm) allows adding the ngNoForm attribute to avoid applying it:

```
selector: 'form:not([ngNoForm]):not([formGroup]),ngForm,[ngForm]',
```

So you can use

```
<form ngNoForm ... >
```

to have a plain old form.